# How to consider taking dot in the number in regular expression

Tags: c++, regex

Take a look at the following regular expression

`std::regex reg("[A][-+]?([0-9]*\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)");`

This will find any A letter followed by float number. The problem if the number `A30.`, this regular expression ignores the dot and print the result as `A30`. I would like to force the regular expression to consider the decimal dot as well. Is this feasible?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    std::string line("A50. hsih Y0 his ");
    std::smatch match;
    std::regex reg("[A][-+]?([0-9]*\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)");   

    if ( std::regex_search(line,match,reg) ){
            cout << match.str(0) << endl;

        }else{
            cout << "nothing found" << endl;
        }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to match that dot after an int value you may use `reg(R"(A[-+]?\d+\.?\d*)")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You request the dot to be followed by one or more (+) digits.  Just make the trailing ditigs optional by changing it to:

```
std::regex reg("[A][-+]?([0-9]*\\.[0-9]*|[0-9]+)");
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/G6ilhA)

The only problem with this expression is that it would also match A followed by a single dot without any digit. I don't know if you'd see this a s a valid match.  A more robust alternative would hence be:

```
std::regex reg("[A][-+]?([0-9]*\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\\.?)");
```

So either trailing digits, or digits followed optionally by a dot.

[Second demo](https://ideone.com/pwGtZ1)

Comment: Even my *fixed* answer was wrong. Can't win them all. Deleted. The answer of @Christophe looks good. He was quicker with the regexes today than I. I'll beat him next time!

Answer (score 1):

You can change your regex like this

```
A[-+]?(?:[0-9]*\\.?(?:[0-9]+)?)
```

- `A` - Matches `A`.
- `[-+]?` - Matches `+` or `-`. ( ? makes it optional)
- `(?:[0-9]*\\.?(?:[0-9]+)?)`

  - `(?:[0-9]*\\.` - will match zero or more digits followed by `.` (? makes it optional)
  - `(?:[0-9]+)?`  - Matches one or more time. (? makes it optional)

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/SuCKZT/6/)